# Vb.net Move a Picture in a PictureBox to another PictureBox

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a game in vb.net and I am trying to move a picture in a picturebox to another picturebox. But i can't get it to work.

```
Dim ChestPlate As Image = My.Resources.ChestPlate

Private Sub pictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pictureBox1.Click

    If pictureBox1.Image Is ChestPlate Then

        pictureBox2.Image = ChestPlate

        pic1tureBox1.Image = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it bug out? Does picture two only remain blank or do both pictures go blank?

Comment: Nothing happends, picturebox1 has the picture and picturebox2 has not a picture.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you cant compare images by just using "=" in .NET. There are many answers on StackOveflow about this. There are third party libraries you can use to do what you want. You can also check out this Microsoft library link, although i dont know if it will work [ImageComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191601.aspx). If you are working with small images you can compare every pixel to see if the images match.

```
'checks if two images are the same by comparing each pixel. not very fast for large images.
Private Function AreSameImage(ByVal bitmap1 As Bitmap, ByVal bitmap2 As Bitmap) As Boolean

    For X = 0 To bitmap1.Width - 1
        For y = 0 To bitmap2.Height - 1
            If bitmap1.GetPixel(X, y) <> bitmap2.GetPixel(X, y) Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next
    Next

'If every pixel matched, return true
    Return True
End Function
```

And then for your click event:

```
Dim ChestPlate As Image = My.Resources.ChestPlate

Private Sub pictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pictureBox1.Click

If AreSameImage(picturebox1.image ,Chestplate) Then

    pictureBox2.Image = ChestPlate

    pic1tureBox1.Image = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```

Check out this link:[How to make comparison in VB.NET](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d80970b9-303a-4bf6-8b7f-7bdde93a2c00/how-to-make-comparison-between-pictures-in-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral)

Also for future reference the "is" keyword does not check for value equality rather for object equality, so even if the images are the same since they are different objects it will return false.[C# IS Keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

Comment: Sorry I am very new at vb. When I typed  "If AreSameImage(pictureBox1, ChestPlate) Then" Then it was an error with pictureBox1. "Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.bitmap".

Comment: Sorry, you need picturebox1.image. I will correct my answer

Comment: Thank you so much!